# What does pristine mean?

Tags: angular, forms

I'm french and I'm seeing this function in the Angular doc! "markAsPristine()" that set the form as "pristine".
I've searched the translation of that word but I still don't really get what's the point.

If someone can explain me what it is used for in a dev way because the translation doesn't help me.

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the English language

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pristine

Comment: the opposite of pristine is dirty (becomes false when you make a key stroke in the input), the opposite of untouched is touched (becomes false when you make a key stroke **and** lost focus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pristine tells that the form has not been modified by the user. Returns true if the form has not been modified by the user.